# Reference Request: connection between PIE \*leg- and \*les

Tags: historical-linguistics, proto-indo-european

There's an obvious similarity between the Proto-Indo-European reconstructed roots *leg- and *les-, both "to collect, gather", reflected in *logos*, Latin *lego* and German *lesen* respectively. I have not yet seen a comparison of the roots, and did not research explicitly, other than looking up Wiktionary.

I am hoping someone knows a reference from the top of their head.

---

I see three possibilities:

1. There is a common root to the two reconstructions and a grammatical explanation for the dissimalirity.

   1.a) *lesen* did not have the connotation of *reading*. The sense is a phono-semantic loan from a christian incurser.

   1.b) "lesen" had the connotation *to pick up hints* for long.
2. Both roots were the same but at different stages; Which would imply sound change not shared by both branches as early as in a PIE dialect scenario or at the latest in a scenario in which noble savage learns to read from forreigners--similar to 1.a)--and borrows the whole word mutating it slightly (Galician *lesen*, 3rd p. pl. subjunctive participle of *ler* "to read" < *legere*, reminds of Ger *belesen* "learned")

I'm sure that there is no main-stream hypothesis, otherwise I'd expect Wiktionary to note that. I'm pretty sure there are at best non-comittal opinions or unacceptable fringe theories at worst about questions concerning the timeline of PIE and unproven sound-changes. I think it is impossible to give an acceptable negative answer

I'd be surprised if a tentative synchronic explanation has been given on the example of exactly these two roots. A general grammatic theory to synthesize an answer would probably be beyond me; I expect I will not find the answer in introductory text-books (if that constitutes lack of prior research, the question should be closed, or put on hold for a *long* while).

So i guess I'm asking: Have I missed another principle possibility?

<sub>This could be deemed to broad and unlikely to result in a high quality answer and more likely to result in a low effort answer about the uncertainties of etymology, which would be yet too much effort to ask, for what it's worth, on the basis of the question.</sub>

What I really want to know is actually:

**Is there a theory for a root *le-?-**? Ideally, that should explain a few other *l- initial roots as well, perhaps even *glossa*.

Comment: A root *le- is impossible given PIE root structure (see e.g. https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/a/7272/2411). All the two roots have in common is initial l-, so the similarity is probably coincidental.

Comment: It may be coincidence, or the two might have some relationship in pre-PIE times—there's no way to really say one way or the other, since the comparative method can't go back any farther than PIE (unless some exciting new evidence appears).

Comment: @TRK, that's why I wrote "\*le-?-". Also, \*so, \*de, \*ye etc exist. Suppose an aorist \*l-H and the reflex would be \*l- in most branches. Maybe "root" is not the correct etymology, sure.

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood the question mark. (But note that *so etc. aren't verbal roots.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At the time when Proto-Indogermanic was spoken, there wasn't any written form of it. It is therefore quite clear, that it also hadn't a word with the modern meaning of "to read". German usage like *Kartoffeln lesen* or *Trauben lesen* still preserve the old meaning "to collect".

The root form of Latin *lego* and many other words is **leǵ* with a ǵ that becomes palatalized in the Satem languages as shown by an Iranian cognate. The synonymity between **les* and **leǵ* is indeed strange, but I am not aware of a deeper explanation. My first guess would be that in Germanic we have for some reason applied a partial satemization to that root or borrowed it from a Satem language at an early stage in its history, but the existence of a Hittite (*li-iš-ša-an-zi*) cognate to *lesen* makes this hypothesis less plausible.

I don't think that you can deduct anything from one single instance, where **-ǵ* and **-s* are synonym forming endings; especially not even the fact that they are suffixes to a shorter root **le*.

Another note: The Galician form *lesen* is a pure coincidence, the /s/ there does not come from the /g/ in leger, but from the ending, compare Catalan *lleguessin* with preserved /g/.

EDIT: The r in the Galician infinitve *ler* is also not part of the root, it goes back to the Latin infinitive ending *-re*. So no connection to German *lernen* "to learn" here.

P.S. For Some alternations in Protoindogermanic that occur with a greater frequency, see this question and its answers: [Can these new etymological pairs of PIE roots be true?](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/questions/27634/can-these-new-etymological-pairs-of-pie-roots-be-true)